# USB акселерометр

Tags: c++, usb

Поставили задачу написать программу, получающую данные от 5-8 подключенных по USB плат  [MOD-MMA7260Q](http://www.olimex.com/dev/pdf/OTHER/MOD-MMA7260Q.pdf). Там приводится пример с 3D Mouse, но я, честно говоря, ничерта не понял. Подскажите с чего начать, куда копать. Если возможно - простенький пример кода как с этим работать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Определиться, в какой операционной системе вы будете работать с USB-устройством
2. Разобраться как в выбранной ОС осуществляется доступ к USB-устройствам, работающим в режиме HID
3. Научиться распознавать факт подключения устройства по vendorID и deviceID
4. Научиться перехватывать и обрабатывать сообщения, поступающие от HID-устройств

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще один вариант - использовать прошивку для контроллера, реализующую виртуальный COM. Простой в плане необходимого ПО со стороны компьютера и легко переносимый с одной ОС на другую(в виду наличия готовых драйверов). Atmel предоставляет для своих контроллеров фреймворк, в котором есть все необходимое. Такой вариант может быть рассмотрен?

Comment: Да, COM это первое о чем я подумал. Но насколько это реально с данной платой представления не имею.